# What is a stereo pair of samples called?

Tags: audio, digital, terminology

I'm a part of a development team working on an audio processing application. We have the silliest problem that's already caused us some trouble coding. We work with stereo audio signals, and when someone says *sample* (as in 44100 samples per second), it can either mean a mono sample or a stereo pair of samples. People tend to use there interchangeably, and that drives everyone nuts. Is there a standard name for a stereo pair of samples?

Comment: I call them Obscure Robots, in honor of myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe "frame" is the term you're looking for - the set of samples from every channel for a given point in time.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Yes, indeed you're right! = )

Comment: yes, I think this is right, although it can get confusing since MP3 has "frames" that are a single block of compressed samples.

Comment: In addition, frames on an audio CD are 1/75th of a second.